# Filtering a nested collection using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes, one nested within the other,

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string SSN;
    public List<Car> CarsOwnedByHim;

}
```

and another class car

```
class Car
{
    public string RegNo; 
    public string Make;
    public string ModelName;
}
```

from a `List<Person>` I would like to filter out all the cars of , say ModelName = "Corolla".

Note that the person instance should be returned, but in the nested list only the cars should be filtered out.

The below solution is working, but I am looking for a more elegant soution.

```
List<Person> lstPersons = new List<Person>();
foreach (var person in _result)
{
    List<Car> lstCars = new List<Car>();
    foreach (var car in person)
    {
        if (car.ModelName != "Corolla")
            lstCars.Add(car);
    }
    var tempPerson = person;
    tempPerson.CarsOwnedByHim = lstCars;
    lstPersons.Add(tempPerson);

}
return lstPersons ;
```

This is just a modified version of the original problem.TIA.

Comment: Are you aware that `var tempPerson = person;` does not make a copy of the instance? You are replacing the car list on the original person.

Comment: yup, thats fine, I am just looking for a linq based solution. This is a simplified version of the original problem

Comment: Do you mean asymptotic elegance or aesthetic elegance; for unless you revisit the approach itself, the former is not conceivable. If it just about using linq, it is more or less the same thing as you have already shared - as shared by others below.

Comment: looking for a linq based solution, I had mentioned it in the comment above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. You can get `list` of cars of a person where make is `not equal` to corolla by using `Where` clause like this

```
lstCars = person.CarsOwnedByHim.Where(x => x.ModelName.ToUpper() != "COROLLA").ToList();
```

Yor whole code would be like this

```
List<Person> lstPersons = new List<Person>();
foreach (var person in _result)
{
    List<Car> lstCars = new List<Car>();
    lstCars=person.CarsOwnedByHim.Where(x => x.ModelName.ToUpper() != "COROLLA").ToList();
    person.CarsOwnedByHim = lstCars;
    lstPersons.Add(person);

}
return lstPersons ;
```

Comment: Why are you still using `tempPerson`? It's the same object as `person`, so it would be clearer (and exactly equivalent) to say `person.CarsOwnedByHim = lstCars; lstPersons.Add(person);`

Comment: @Blorgbeard you are right i just showed how to filter the list i will update the answer to remove this extra code thanks.

Comment: This could conceivably be incredibly inefficient since it uses Lazy Loading.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an abridged lambda version for you:

```
persons.ForEach(p => p.CarsOwnedByHim.RemoveAll(c => c.ModelName == "Corolla"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of people with Corollas removed, and leave the original list alone:

```
var lstPersons = (
    from p in _result
    select new Person() {
        Name = p.Name,
        SSN = p.SSN,
        CarsOwnedByHim = p.CarsOwnedByHim.Where(t=>t.ModelName != "Corolla").ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

If you want to edit the original list:

```
foreach (var person in _result)
    person.CarsOwnedByHim = 
        person.CarsOwnedByHim
        .Where(t=>t.ModelName != "Corolla")
        .ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross join like this

```
var combo = from p in Person
            from c in cars.Where(t=>t.ModelName != "Corolla")
            select new
            {
                Name=p.Name,
                SSN=p.SSN,
                CarsOwnedByHim=c.ToList()
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Using linq is awesome:

```
List<Car> carStatus =
    (from car in person
      where car.ModelName != "Corolla"
      select car).ToList();
```

Make sure to include the using statement for linq

You can have unlimited where clauses just add it under the first where

```
List<Car> carStatus =
    (from car in person
      where car.ModelName != "Corolla"
      where car.Color == "blue"
      select car).ToList();
```

Make sure you do .ToList or .Single or .SingleOrDefault at the end to query the data, it's not queried until you call them with .ToList or something like that.

If you want to select sub models or properties you can do it in the select:

```
List<Car> carStatus =
    (from car in person
      where car.ModelName != "Corolla"
      where car.Color == "blue"
      select car.ModelName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var cars = (from p in persons
        from c in p.CarsOwnedByHim
        where c.ModelName == "Corolla"
        select c).ToList();
```